# How to query all lines in a file that are NOT equal or suffix of any name in another file

Tags: grep, regular-expression, string, search

I have two files `file1` and `file2`. The two files contain names. One name in each line. I want to query all names in `file2` that are `not equal to` or a `suffix of` name in `file1`. Note that the prefix is identified by any characters followed by a dot (`.`) then the suffix.

For example. If `file2`contains `f2name` in a line, and `file1` contains `sub.f2name` then `f2name` is a suffix for a name in `file1` and we do not want to put it in the result.

Another example is `sub1.sub2.f2name`. The `names` in `file1` can be preceded by any number of prefixes (characters separated by dots). The names of `file2` can appear as suffix for any number of prefixes or can be equal to names in `file1`.

I need to query names in `file2` that are not equal to and are not suffix of any number of prefixes of names in `file1`.
For example: `file2` contains:

```
bb.com
a.com
123.com
```

`file1` contains:

```
aa.bb.com
aa.ff.bb.com
aa.bb.cc.com
a.com
```

The names I want are those in `file2` not equal to and are not suffix of names in `file1`. i.e.:

```
123.com
```

The reason for the output:
`a.com` in `file2` is equal to a name in `file1`: `aa.bb.com`
And `bb.com`from `file2` is suffix of `aa.ff.bb.com` and `aa.bb.com` in `file1` (note: prefixes can be repeated more than one or two. The point is that it ends with a name in `file2`).

I have tried to use MySQL to make a query. But file2 contains 3 million line and file1 contains 1 million. MySQL could not perform well. Does Linux has commands that can perform such query in a reasonable time?

Comment: Why are you requesting 'aa.bb.cc.com' to be printed? It is not in the source file2 in your question.

Comment: @Isaac thanks. Corrected now. If you have an answer can you please tell me if it can be performed in a reasonable time (not more than an hour)? file2 is 3 million line, file1 is 1 million.

Comment: Could it happen that one line in file1 (like hh.ii.jj.com) is longer than all the (matching) lines in file2 (like ii.jj.com) ?

Comment: @Isaac sorry I don't get your question. What do you mean by longer? your example is like the examples I pointed. Yes ideally if the name in file2 exist as a suffix in file1, then that name in file1 will be longer.

Comment: The lines are unique in both files BTW. But names in file2 can occur as a suffix in more than line in file1. Hope this clarify.

Comment: The examples you present are shorter in file2 (like `bb.com` is shorter than `aa.bb.com`), could it happen that the entry in file 2 is longer (has more names) (like rr.ss.ff.aa.bb.com in file 2 while the matching file1 entry is only aa.bb.com). I suppose that in this case one is not a sub-string (suffix) of the other and should be rejected.

Comment: If there is common strings in both files, the name in file2 is either equal to or shorter than (suffix) the name in file1. file2 name can not be longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how efficient this will be, for your input, but here's a possible strategy:

1. turn the lines of `file2` into line-anchored regex patterns

   ```
   sed -e 's/\./\\./g' -e 's/$/\$/' file2
   ```
2. pipe the patterns into grep to output only the matching portions of `file1`

   ```
   ... | grep -of - file1
   ```
3. (optional) uniquify the results
4. plain-text search `file2` for the matching entries

   ```
   ... | grep -vxFf - file2
   ```

Ex.

```
$ sed -e 's/\./\\./g' -e 's/$/\$/' file2 | 
    grep -of - file1 | 
    sort -u | 
    grep -vxFf - file2
123.com
```

*If the entries in `file2` contain regex-special characters besides `.` these will also need to be escaped.*

Comment: Having a quadratic time complexity, it is not a good solution. But also, the match is not on dot boundaries.